# SSD dedicated to swap-only fails on Debian or Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, swap, shutdown, ssd

It did not happen to me yet, but if I dedicate a single SSD (non-RAID) to swap-ONLY and the server system is using it to full capacity - what happens next? How am I to recover, assuming I have an identical, tested and working SSD in my hands, biting my nails to deal with it?

Let us assume I have an i3, 32GB RAM server running the latest XUbuntu with xfce. On top of that I am running Oracle's 4.3.20 VirtualBox (vbox), home to many Windows and Linux servers and clients.

I understand there are a few scenarios.

Scenario A: I share the SSD swap-only drive used by the XUbuntu host with the vbox Linux client's swap files and Windows client's page file.

Scenario B: I isolate the XUbuntu host from VirtualBox: my vbox clients never use the hosting Linux's SSD drive for swap. Instead I restart the virtual clients to use more physical resources.

Scenario C: I never allow any vbox client to go over half of 32GB, and I force the vbox clients to use their own virtual swap.

Whatever the scenario is the SSD is now gone, and I need to deal with it.

I am VERY much tempted to go with Scenario A, as it is the most suitable drive for swap and page files, but if the recovery from such failure is complex or impossible, please let me know. B and C is safe, but very limiting.

Again, this is only a scenario and it did not happen to me yet. Thanks for reading!

Comment: SSDs sound like a terrible idea for swap space.

Comment: @Shadur: I would've agreed wholeheartedly a few years ago, but (allegedly) SSDs are a lot more robust these days. And a lot cheaper, so it kinda makes sense. I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

Linux can use multiple swap partitions or swap files, so if you're afraid that the SSD will run out of space simply have a spare swap partition or file for it to use. Normally, swap usage is interleaved across all available swap devices & files, but you can override that be assigning priorities to your swap devices.

From http://linux.die.net/man/8/swapon

> -p, --priority priority
>
> Specify the priority of the swap device. *priority* is a value between 0 and 
>   32767. Higher numbers indicate higher priority. 
>   See swapon(2) for a full description of swap priorities.
>   Add `pri=value` to the option field of `/etc/fstab` for use with `swapon -a`.

And from http://linux.die.net/man/2/swapon

> Swap pages are allocated from areas in priority order, highest
>   priority first. For areas with different priorities, a higher-priority
>   area is exhausted before using a lower-priority area. If two or more
>   areas have the same priority, and it is the highest priority
>   available, pages are allocated on a round-robin basis between them.

So just make your main swap partitions / files on the SSD have the same priority and give your "emergency" swap on a normal HD a lower priority.

IIRC, it's more efficient to use swap partitions than swap files; OTOH, using files is slightly more flexible, and the extra overhead is pretty small, but I guess the slight speed difference may be more noticeable when using an SSD rather than a traditional HD, since the SSD is so fast.

FWIW, it's **not** a good idea to share swap spaces between different OSes if you are using hibernation!

Comment: Just to make this sure... How do you discard a failed and only SSD used for swap? Not files but an entire drive...

Comment: I am beginning to see. I was always suspecting that 64GB of RAM on one SSD might not do as long as there is not at least another 64GB RAM on the same. When it comes to swap, under-estimating is as good as loosing the very system purpose?

Comment: @MP 2Ring - It is that simple - 'swapon' and just get rid of the failed SSD - I was hoping for that. Of course, I would have SSD's 64GB swaps all over the place.

Comment: @arch-abit Assuming your SSD supports hot-swapping, you should be able to deactivate it with swapoff, unplug the SSD, plug in the replacement and activate it. But I've never tried that myself. FWIW, if you frequently run out of RAM so that you _need_ to use swap it will put a lot of wear & tear on the swap drive. And that may shorten its useful life. But I guess 32GB of SSD is cheaper than 32GB of RAM...

Comment: Any SSD is cheaper than a non-working server, so I guess plugging it full of SSDs as RAM might worth it for now.

Comment: vm.swapiness=xx is not in /etc/sysctl.cfg. I have two Linux installs, one XUbuntu I change and the other one that works and I do not - neither has it in /etc/sysctl.cfg so I guess I am going to add it to the one that changes - after all, that is what it does - change?

Comment: 60 on the workstation I am posting from, thanks! 60 is the default and this is at least a 3 years old XUbuntu installation.

Comment: It is a Dual Core 32-bit with 3.5GB of RAM, and it worked wonderfully. It had Windows Vista with 2x250GB SATA RAID, and my roommate sold it to me as such... It is a good xfce machine, it served me for at least three years with no problems ever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19975/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-arch-abit).